# How to insert null value when doing left join in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these 2 table (each element is in column):

```
TABLE A: 
ID  1  2  3 4 5
TD  20 10 0 1 7

TABLE B:
ID  2  3 
TD  40 30
```

I want to do a LEFT JOIN to obtain a FINAL_TABLE in which I have all the ID od TABLE A and the one of table B in common with A. I want also that in case there is ID in TABLE A and not in TABLE B (ex. ID 1,4,5), in the FINAL_TABLE I will show NULL at that ID.
The FINAL_TABLE should be (see all in column):

```
ID  1    2  3  4    5
TDA 20   10 0  1    7
TDB NULL 40 30 NULL NULL
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Are `ID` and `TD` the columns names in your tables and the columns in the example are just rows in  the tables?

Comment: Consider a transposed configuration of the one showed here

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if this is what you ask for, but perhaps you just want to add one result to another?

```
select 'TDA', col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 from tableA
UNION ALL
select 'TDB', null, col1, col2, null, null from tableB
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. Could you please try this once.

```
    INSERT INTO FINAL_TABLE
    (
        ID,
        tdA,
        tdB
    )
    SELECT 
        A.ID,
        A.td,
        B.td
    FROM
        TABLEA 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEB ON (A.ID=B.ID)
    GROUP BY
        A.ID,
        A.td,
        B.td
    ;
```

Comment: This works, but I want instead that in the cell is shown NULL instead of Zero value. I used this:CASE WHEN condition THEN NULL ELSE correct value. It seems to work!

Comment: Thanks. If it has worked for you, could you please accept this answer.@Giovanna